# Python version of MAP_2POINTS

Tags: python, extents, idl

I think I may have stumbled onto an **IDL** function which does not have a python equivalent... :'(

I am working with a Whiskbroom imaging radiometer ([Terra/Aqua MODIS](http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/)), with a corresponding bounding box such as [*UL, UR, LR, LL*] Latitude/Longitude for the final image.

I also have a point located somewhere else (maybe outside the image, maybe inside) I'll call *PX*

What I want to do is:

1. Find the midpoint between *UL* and *UR* points, and between *LR* and *LL*
2. I want an array of Latitude/Longitude coordinates for a line that connects those midpoints
3. For all items in the array, I want to see if the great-circle distance to the *PX* is less than 55km

Basically, I just want to see if my point (PX) fell almost at Nadir for my imager (if Nadir is within 55km of the center line)...

In **IDL** I can implement this by the [MAP_2POINTS](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/MAP_2POINTS.html) function:

```
cpt=MAP_2POINTS(UL_Lon, UL_Lat, UR_Lon, UR_Lat, NPATH=3)
cpt2=MAP_2POINTS(LR_Lon, LR_Lat, LL_Lon, LL_Lat, NPATH=3)
nad=MAP_2POINTS(cpt(0,1), cpt(1,1), cpt2(0,1), cpt2(1,1), NPATH=2001)
ndist=fltarr(2001)
for q=0,2000 do begin
   ndist(q)=(MAP_2POINTS(PX_Lon, PX_Lat, nad(0,q), nad(1,q), /METERS))/1000
endfor
```

Is there any simple way to do this in **Python2.7**?

Comment: Do you have access to the ArcGIS `arcpy` site package?

Comment: Not at the moment. Should I look into it?

Answer (score 1):

I mean, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24114565/1533001) is kind of close:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
from rtree import index

cdat = {'UR_Lon': 39.44,
        'LR_Lat': 18.89,
        'LL_Lon': 10.69,
        'LL_Lat': 21.95,
        'UL_Lon': 12.87,
        'LR_Lon': 33.02,
        'UL_Lat': 40.28,
        'UR_Lat': 36.44}

PX_Lat, PX_Lon =28.55, 23.39

# List of non-overlapping polygons
polygons = [
    Polygon([(cdat['UL_Lat'], cdat['UL_Lon']),
             (cdat['UR_Lat'], cdat['UR_Lon']),
             (cdat['LR_Lat'], cdat['LR_Lon']),
             (cdat['LL_Lat'], cdat['LL_Lon'])])
]

# Populate R-tree index with bounds of polygons
idx = index.Index()
for pos, poly in enumerate(polygons):
    idx.insert(pos, poly.bounds)

# Query a point to see which polygon it is in
# using first Rtree index, then Shapely geometry's within
point = Point(PX_Lat, PX_Lon)
poly_idx = [i for i in idx.intersection((point.coords[0]))
            if point.within(polygons[i])]
if len(poly_idx) == 1:
    print cdat
```

I just need a way to condense the `Polygon` call to only be +/- 55km from the center of the swath (along the velocity vector)...